# Is the word 'recipe' an abstract noun?

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

I'm studying English to teach as a foreign language and can't completely grasp the difference between concrete and abstract nouns. 
For example, "recipe" is a noun. I understand that a recipe card would be a concrete noun but would recipe alone be an abstract noun i.e. an idea?

TIA 
Eloise

Comment: A recipe can be a set of specific instructions as in "a recipe for eggs", as well as the more abstract "a recipe for disaster." Does [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/recipe) cover it?

Comment: A single word can have both concrete and abstract senses. A 'football' may be bought, kicked, washed, popped, thrown away. You can have 2, 3....  But then 'football' (UK usage) can mean the whole over-arching institution, and beyond. From Messi to that hopeless guy in the end-terrace (me a few years back), from the local park to the San Siro. 'Soccer' in the US (though the connotations are vastly different). // Then there's the problem of classifying say 'laughter'. Abstract (no substance) or concrete (discernable)? // I've heard "She threw the recipe in the bin", so a concrete **usage**.

Comment: _Recipe_ can refer to a text (which is pretty abstract, but is precise and can be repeated or analyzed), any number of physical objects that present it (like a file card, which is totally concrete), or some completely imaginary -- hence abstract -- metaphorical use, like _recipe for disaster_. No noun is ever always abstract, just like no verb is ever always transitive.

Comment: Nope. It is a piece of paper than lists ingredience

Comment: @JohnLawler - If no noun is ever always abstract, how does one make dread or wistfulness concrete? Can you please expand on what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Easy; use them to name something. It's the opposite of metaphor, which makes abstractions by mismatching concrete phenomena.

Comment: Thanks for these responses, @JohnLawler you were particularly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

[John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524879/is-the-word-recipe-an-abstract-noun#comment1279033_524879) wrote:

> *Recipe* can refer to a text (which is pretty abstract, but is precise and can be repeated or analyzed), any number of physical objects that present it (like a file card, which is totally concrete), or some completely imaginary — hence abstract — metaphorical use, like *recipe for disaster*. No noun is ever always abstract, just like no verb is ever always transitive.

[nnnnnn](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524879/is-the-word-recipe-an-abstract-noun#comment1279114_524879) asked:

> If no noun is ever always abstract, how does one make dread or wistfulness concrete? Can you please expand on what I'm misunderstanding?

[John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524879/is-the-word-recipe-an-abstract-noun#comment1279116_524879) clarified:

> Easy; use them to name something. It's the opposite of metaphor, which makes abstractions by mismatching concrete phenomena.