# Abstract and concrete nouns

Tags: nouns, vocabulary, abstract-nouns

I am still confused with the classifications of such nouns as *area*, *spot*, *compound* (which refers to a type of area), and *area* itself. Are they abstract or concrete nouns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an English dictionary that distinguishes words as either abstract or concrete?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124470/is-there-an-english-dictionary-that-distinguishes-words-as-either-abstract-or-co) The best answer here is that the terms 'concrete' and 'abstract' are often considered archaic (at least) nowadays, and more sound analysis rejects a clear dichotomy here.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks. I've been searching for such a dictionary.

Comment: Note that _usages_, not _nouns_, need to be considered. 'Corner' is used very differently in 'The corner of the box is damaged' and 'Messi has scored from a corner'. As is 'fields' in 'These fields have been sown with wheat' and 'Psychiatry and psychology are, of course, closely related fields'.

Comment: Now, what if it were *the school compound is always clean*. Would it be an abstract noun there?

Comment: It depends on your chosen definition of 'compound' (does it include shrubs, air space ...?) and your chosen psycholinguistic analyst who still persists with a simplistic notion of 'abstractness'. I suggest you read Professor Lawler's wisdom at the [Is _recipe_ an abstract noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/524879/is-the-word-recipe-an-abstract-noun) thread. There is a thread somewhere mentioning a more satisfactory classification than the crude concrete v abstract attempt.